Is Bangladesh seeking short range ballistic missile from Pakistan?

IDRW: bangladesh seeks pakistani srbms for deterrence against India, intel reports confirm

Bangladesh seeks short-range ballistic missiles from Pakistan



According to a report quoted by defense website Indian Defence Research Wing (IDRW), Bangladesh has approached Pakistan to procure the Abdali SRBM, which has a range of 400 km, apparently to act as a deterrent against an attack by India.

Is Bangladesh seeking short range ballistic missile from Pakistan?
